# rxjs Subject не передает значения подписчикам

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular2, angular, rxjs

У меня есть приложение, которое обрабатывает запрос пользователя на покупку конкретных товаров и добавляет их в корзину. Для менеджмента этих действий я использую Subject и Subscription. Запрос на товары из API проходит хорошо - все товары выводятся, но абсолютно аналогичная операция с кликом на кнопку и добавлением в новый массив не дает ничего. Никакие данные не эмитятся. Я подписан на правильный Subject... вроде. Не понимаю, в чем дело, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
// переменные 
  inCart: Item[] = [];
  itemsChanged = new Subject<Item[]>();

// метод добавления 

  addProduct(id) {
    const addedItem = this.shoppingCart.find((item) => item.id === id);
    this.inCart.push(addedItem);
    console.log(this.inCart); // выводит новый элемент корзины
    this.addedItemsChanged.next(this.inCart.slice());
  }

// подписка в дочернем компоненте, не получает ничего 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemsChangedSub = this.ShoppingCartService.addedItemsChanged.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.length > 0) {
          this.changedItems = data;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

При использовании метода .slice() нужно как минимум передавать индекс начала копирования. В этом примере: this.addedItemsChanged.next(this.inCart.slice(0));

Comment: ніт https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286950/using-the-javascript-slice-method-with-no-arguments